# TypeScript dynamic import html module like Angular

Tags: typescript, webpack, dynamic-import

I am a newbie typescript webpack. And I wonder how Angular work.
Now, I am stucking in import html file from **parent** of typescript class. Here is my sample

```
// src/components/HomeComponent.ts
// src/components/HomeComponent.xhtml

import {BaseTemplatedWidget, Component} from '../lib/BaseWidget';

@Component({
    selector: "HomeComponent",
    templatePath: "./HomeComponent.xhtml"
})
export default class HomeComponent extends BaseTemplatedWidget {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

// Parent Class
export class BaseTemplatedWiget extends BaseWidget {
    templatePath: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this._initMetaData();
    }

    _initMetaData() {
        this.selector = Reflect.getMetadata(symbolSelector, this) || "";
        this.templatePath = Reflect.getMetadata(symbolTemplatePath, this) || "";
    }

    async buildDomNode(): Promise<Element> {
        console.log("# buildDomNode:", this.templatePath);
        try {
            const {default: tempStr} = await import(`${this.templatePath}`);
            let container = document.createElement("div");
            container.innerHTML = tempStr;
            let template: HTMLTemplateElement = container.querySelector("template");
            if (template) this._node = template.content.cloneNode(true) as Element;
        } catch(error) {
            console.log("[error] fail to build DOM node with error", error);
        }
        return this._node;
    }
}
```

Then, from browser I got an error:

> [error] fail to build DOM node with error Error: Cannot find module './HomeComponent.xhtml'

My webpack.config.js

```
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

export default {
  entry: {
    src: "/"
  },
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  node: {__filename: true},
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {component: path.join(__dirname, "/src")},
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.html']
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'html',
      template: './index.html',
      inject: 'head'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['ts-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html|xhtml)$/,
        use: ['html-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss|sass|less)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset',
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I think root problem come from parent class. When I move function buildDomNode to child class HomeComponent -> import templatePath is working well. But, this function should be defined in Base class for reuse.

Comment: Is `HomeComponent.xhtml` located in root directory of project ?

Comment: HomeComponent.xhtml is the same location with HomeComponent.ts